Force gnome remote desktop daemon to use default GPU, not Nvidia dGPU
I'm running a Ubuntu 24.04 VM in Proxmox with a PCI passthrough Nvidia RTX 3060 GPU.
Proxmox setup:

The VNC console in Proxmox works fine, as well as RDP (using Remmina) however if I passthrough the Nvidia GPU to the VM, RDP will only get me to the login screen, after that I get a blank gray screen.
In nvidia-smi I can see that the gnome-remote-desktop daemon is running using the Nvidia GPU.
nvidia-smi output:

How can I force the gnome remote desktop to use the "integrated" GPU provided by Proxmox virtualization?
Default VGA:

